# Physics of harmfull bungee jumping and hanging

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, potential-energy, spring, elasticity

According to [the Wikipedia section on long drop hanging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanging#Long_drop), the risk of decapitation increases with length of the rope.
By analogy I expect that a long enough bungee rope can tear jumper's leg off.

I have tried to infer a formula for the maximum force applied by the rope to the leg/neck. In order to do so, I have assumed that the initial gravitational potential energy ($mg(l + \Delta{}l)$) is fully transformed into elastic potential energy ($\frac{k}{2l}(\Delta{l})^2$).
However, the result I have obtained is **independent** on the length of the relaxed rope ($l$):

$$F_{max} = mg + \sqrt{mg (mg + 2k)} ,$$

where $m$ is the mass of the person, $g$ is the standard acceleration due to gravity. I assume that the force applied to the leg/neck is proportional to the relative extension of the rope ($\frac{\Delta{}l}{l}$):

$F_{\frac{\Delta{}l}{l}} = k \frac{\Delta{}l}{l}$

Therefore I conclude that the safety of jumper's leg does not depend on the length of the rope. Same should apply to the neck - which is contradicted by the empirical evidence.

Are my calculations wrong (I have double checked them) or am I missing something in my model?

Comment: Your units seem to be wrong ($mg$ is $\mathrm{N}$, while $2k$ is $\mathrm{N/m}$); you don't seem to have factored in the period of dropping with the rope/bungee slack; nor do you seem to have asked yourself what values of $k$ you should be using for twisted natural fiber ropes of sufficient breaking strength.

Comment: @dmckee the unit of $k$ is $N$, as $\frac{\Delta{}l}{l}$ is **relative** extension. How shall I factor the period in? I do not understand the part about values of $k$. All my calculations are purely symbolic. I neither plan to hang anyone nor to jump. ;)

Comment: Hmm ... I misunderstood as $k$ is usually used for the spring constant. None the less you still have the issues relating to the ballistic phase of the action and the stiffness of natural fiber ropes.

Comment: @dmckee Isn't stiffness the same as $k l$ in this example? Or do you mean that natural fiber ropes deviate from Hooke's law?
What factors shall I take into account during the ballistic phase? I interpret the "ballistic phase" as free fall (of length $l$), but it has been included by calculating initial gravitational potential energy as $mg(l + \Delta{}l)$.